# Crystal Report with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, crystal-reports

I'm using crystal report in Visual Studio 2008. In my project, I have a report with internal subreport. I use a crystal Report Viewer to show my report. All its work very well when I running website in Visual Studio debug mode, my report shown correctly.

But when I setup my website (on develop PC too) on IIS (Version 8.5, Windows 10 Dev Preview), my report doesn't show and it ask for parameters links between main report and subreport.

Anyone can tell me what are problems and how to resolve this?
Thanks so much.

[image: This is screen when I run with visual studio debug mode, it work well]

[image: And this one when I run in IIS localhost]

Here is my code on Report viewer webcontrol

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int xid = 0;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["preUrl"].ToString()))
        {
            previousUrl = Request.Params["preUrl"].ToString();
        }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["pxid"].ToString()))
    {
        xid = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Params["pxid"].ToString());
    }
    GetDatasource(xid);
    theReport = new ReportDocument();
    theReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/Test.rpt"));
    theReport.SetDataSource(ds);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = theReport;
    firstload = 1;
}

protected int firstload
{
    get { return (int?)ViewState["firstload"] ?? 0; }
    set { ViewState["firstload"] = value; }
}
protected void GetDatasource(int xid)
{
    if (firstload == 0)
    {
        //dsReportSanxuat ds = new dsReportSanxuat();
        SqlDataAdapter sAdp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlDataAdapter sAdpDu = new SqlDataAdapter();
        ds = new dsReportSanxuat();
        sAdp = oreport.GetReportSanxuatAdp(xid);
        sAdpDu = oreport.GetReportSanxuatDuAdp(xid);
        sAdp.Fill(ds, "dtReportSanxuat");
        sAdpDu.Fill(ds, "dtReportDu");
        firstload = 1;
    }
}
protected dsReportSanxuat ds
{
    get {
        return (dsReportSanxuat)ViewState["ds"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["ds"] = value;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all. My problem was resolved. If you need answer, it's my PC is 64bit base OS, I've just "Enable 32 bit" on IIS Application Pool then it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I needed to do this for an on-premise client installation.